# CASE Statement with ISNULL(0,'')

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, coalesce, isnull

I would expect the following `SQL statement` to return `b`.

Can you point out what I am doing wrong?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(0,'')='' THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END
```

Answer (score 6):

It comes from the the casting of the data types. You compare an integer to a character

If you run

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(CAST(0 AS VARCHAR(255)),'') = '' THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END
```

you will get b
Otherwise '' will be casted to an integer which is 0 thus making the comparison 0 = 0 which is true and therefore returns 'a'.

Comment: It might be helpful to explain data type precedence as found in this article:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx When an integer and a string are compared, the string is converted to an integer (not the other way around).

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ISNULL(0, '')

Above query returns value 0, so the result is 'a'

Change the query to below, and you will get 'b'

SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL('0','')='' THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END